# install node js in aws linux instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

in linux instance to aws:

i make step by step this tutorial http://iconof.com/blog/how-to-install-setup-node-js-on-amazon-aws-ec2-complete-guide/ but when i went to install npm i couldn't the console show me this error:

```
scripts/doc-build.sh doc/cli/npm-help-search.md man/man1/npm-help-search.1
make[1]: Entering directory `/var/www/html/npm'
node cli.js install marked-man --no-global
bash: node: command not found
make[1]: *** [node_modules/.bin/marked-man] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/www/html/npm'
make: *** [man/man1/npm-help-search.1] Error 2
```

Comment: At what step in the tutorial is that error showing up?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you started with a new instance and did not update it with latest updates or package sources first. You are missing the source for NodeJS packages.

This will add the source and install nodejs:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

Follow this: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions